# How to run an android application APK on IOS?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, android-studio

I am developing android application in android studio. I want that my application can run on IOS as well. what should i do ?

I searched a lot on internet but can't got right or reliable answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run .APK/Android apps on iPad/iPhone devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335874/is-it-possible-to-run-apk-android-apps-on-ipad-iphone-devices)

Comment: [Is it possible to run .apk/ Android applications on an iOS device?](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-run-apk-Android-applications-on-an-iOS-device)

Comment: @Mars this is not duplicate

Comment: @mar in my case i am developing andrid application on android studio and want to run it on IOS .

Comment: Sorry, I mistagged the duplicate and it seems I can't reflag

Comment: You can't run Android application on iOS device. If you could - iOS developers were not needed anymore. But there are some cross-platform development tools, but they are not similar to Android development

Answer (score 1):

A native Android app can’t run on iOS. However their are many ways to build cross platform apps - of course they all have caveats and depending on the complexity of your app a native iOS app may be better.

Cross platform apps.

1. Xamarin- https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/
2. React Native - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/
3. Flutter - https://flutter.dev/

To name a few.

Comment: I studied some where that there may be a Apk or some code of swift integrated with android code.

Comment: This question is almost certainly a duplicate, but I will comment that sometimes it might be preferable to have separate apps for Android and iOS.  This would be the case e.g. where you wanted high performance on both platforms.

Comment: @MIH To my knowledge theirs no APK that allows Android code to compile on iOS. However Google did create Flutter for developers to be able to create cross platform apps - though note it is still relatively new. Their are also rumors that Swift may become a first class language for Android development in the future.

Comment: Perhaps JavaFX (OpenJFX) should be added to that list.